# Error while launching any project from Eclipse on device

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using Eclipse for Android Application Development. It was working fine but I am facing an issue from last two days. I have tried every possible solution to resolve that issue. 
Let me explain the issue first.

Whenever I run or debug a project (any project from work space), it throws error. It shown a crash error on device "Unfortunately, App has stopped."
Then I tried to create a new project. I haven't done any changes in this new project and clicked to launch it on my device. It is also showing the same error. I don't know why it is behaving like that. 
I am in need of your help and will really appreciate your help in this matter.

Here is the logcat error report.

> `03-16 15:13:40.580: E/AndroidRuntime(16681): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-16 15:13:40.580: E/AndroidRuntime(16681): Process: com.chatting.app.facemail, PID: 16681
>   03-16 15:13:40.580: E/AndroidRuntime(16681): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder
>   03-16 15:13:40.580: E/AndroidRuntime(16681):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.initializePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:914)
>   03-16 15:13:40.580: E/AndroidRuntime(16681):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.preparePanel(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:964)
>   03-16 15:13:40.580: E/AndroidRuntime(16681):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.doInvalidatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:1182)
>   03-16 15:13:40.580: E/AndroidRuntime(16681):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.access$100(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:79)
>   03-16 15:13:40.580: E/AndroidRuntime(16681):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase$1.run(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:118)
>   03-16 15:13:40.580: E/AndroidRuntime(16681):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
>   03-16 15:13:40.580: E/AndroidRuntime(16681):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
>   03-16 15:13:40.580: E/AndroidRuntime(16681):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>   03-16 15:13:40.580: E/AndroidRuntime(16681):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
>   03-16 15:13:40.580: E/AndroidRuntime(16681):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   03-16 15:13:40.580: E/AndroidRuntime(16681):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   03-16 15:13:40.580: E/AndroidRuntime(16681):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
>   03-16 15:13:40.580: E/AndroidRuntime(16681):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
>   03-16 15:13:40.580: E/AndroidRuntime(16681):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Comment: the error says that compiler cannot find a class in the Android support v7 library. Have you checked for the presence of the library on the classpath?

Comment: Check Android support v7 library is added properly in your project and available in build path.

Comment: Library is added and I checked it twice. It is running on a tablet but not working on my device S5 Mini.

Answer (score 0):

Each project has it's own R.* class created. Try removing import for R.* and re-adding it but make sure you have the right one referred to your current project

Comment: I have done that but it is still giving the same error.  It is running on a tablet but not working on my device S5 Mini.

Comment: When you created the project, did you specify target SDK correctly? Try using android compiler with the same version of android as your device is (the one that has problem)